# update all records on cakephp

Tags: php, sql, cakephp

I have table called articles on database, (id,title,body,status) ,I made button to call function which update all the column articles.status = 1   ,I want make all articles.status=1 .here's my code but nothing happen. the script by cakephp 1.3

```
function publishall(){

$this->Article->updateAll(
                                array('Article.status' => 1)

                            );
    }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This should be simple to understand. If you are using a controller and you need to load another model, you can call:

```
function publishall(){
    $this->loadModel('Article');
    $this->Article->updateAll(
               'conditions'=> array('Article.status' => 1)
                              );
                       }
```

Comment: thanks Widrogo it work now bcz of your help, but i didn't want condtions i wanted give all records value = 1
$this->loadModel('Article');
$this->Article->updateAll(
               array('Article.status' => 1)
                             );